# Duplicate questions with no answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate

What are we to do when there is a duplicate question (almost identical) with no answers? Check out these two questions:

[Magento2 - How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block)

[Magento2 - How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163848/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block)

Yes they are two different questions.

It looks to me that the second question was a copy and paste of the first with a few small changes. The person who asked the question has also commented on the other question, so they must be aware they're asking a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

well actually we cannot do it for that kind of situation.

Because for marking any question duplicate other question need at least answer with upvote or mark as accepted.

But in this case both question does not have answers and also the second users try to find out the answer but he failed to find the answer, so as per my opinion his question is ok.

Our aim for duplicate question is to stop users to asking same question whose answer is already there.

so as per my opinion this question does not come to that category. still we need comment and expert views from other users what they are thinking.